# enlarge the top spacing of the x axis

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

How can I enlarge the spacing between the x axis labels to the y axis labels?

[image]

Comment: Please put some code so we can understand.

Comment: @ilesh the question is regarding ios-charts framework https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts